# new_node->next update in compare_exchange_weak

Tags: c++, c++11

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

```
template<typename T>
class stack
{
    std::atomic<node<T>*> head;
 public:
    void push(const T& data)
    {
      node<T>* new_node = new node<T>(data);

      // put the current value of head into new_node->next
      new_node->next = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

      // now make new_node the new head, but if the head
      // is no longer what's stored in new_node->next
      // (some other thread must have inserted a node just now)
      // then put that new head into new_node->next and try again
      while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node,
                                        std::memory_order_release,
                                        std::memory_order_relaxed))
          ; // the body of the loop is empty
    }
};
```

I have difficulties to understand how the `new_node->next` will be automatically pointing to the new head if there is another thread that has inserted a new node. For more generic cases, where the variable `head` is not necessary a single linked list, how the `compare_exchange_weak` works in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node)` performs an atomic operation that is roughly equivalent to:

```
if (head == new_node->next) {
    head = new_node;
    return true;
}
else {
    new_node->next = head;
    return false;
}
```

So if no other thread has called `push()`, `head` will compare equal to `new_node->next` so we update `head` to point to `new_node` instead. If some other thread had called `push()`, the comparison will fail, so we update `new_node->next` to point to what is now the new `head` and repeat until we succeed.